# How to compare two app services settings in azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

How can I compare the App Service configuration settings in two different App Services?

Comment: Do you want to compare web app appsettings?

Comment: If yes, `(Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name shuicli -ResourceGroupName shuiapp).SiteConfig.Appsettings` export it to a csv file

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com) to navigate to and view a JSON representation of the conifguration of an App Service. This is built into Azure and doesn't require additional tooling.

For a Proof-of-Concept application I have, I navigated it as such:

```
subscriptions
  -> My Subscription
    -> resourceGroups
      -> My PoC Apps
        -> providers
          -> Microsoft.Web
            -> sites
              -> MyTestApp
                -> config (click on config for some, expand it and browse children for other config)`
```

I'm assuming you know how to compare two different blocks of JSON via various means (DIFF tools, etc), so I won't explain that part.

Answer (score 0):

You can you PowerShell to get all the configuration details of your app services

Login to your Azure Subscription using `Login-AzureRmAccount`

To get all Configuration Settings execute below command.

```
Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name YourAppServiceName1;Get-AzureRmWebApp -Name YourAppServiceName2
```